# How to get iOS7.0 Simulator in xcode6.1 or xcode6.2

Tags: ios7, xcode6, ios-simulator, xcode6.1, xcode-6.2

I am using **Xcode 6.1 in Yosemite** right now, I want to check my app in **iOS7.0 simulator**. I cant able to install from Xcode preferences, above 7.1 simulator only available.

How to get 7.0 Simulator from older xcode or copy paste something like that ?

I copied 7.0 simulator from Xcode 5.0 seed version and pasted into this path > Macintosh HD ▸ Applications ▸ Xcode 3 ▸ Contents ▸ Developer ▸ Platforms ▸ iPhoneSimulator.platform ▸ Developer
but no use i cant see in xcode devices selection.

Comment: You simply can't have this version on Xcode 6.1 with Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it thru Libraries. 
You have to click on About Xcode and click Preference. and then click downloads. It will allow you to get what you're need

Comment: I checked preferences too, it shows up with 7.1. 7.0 not available.